# How can i make all v-text-field components outlined by default in nuxt/vuetify module

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

i'm using the nuxt/vuetify module and would like to make all *v-text-field*s components **outlined**.
Try to create and register plugin which register new vue component, that extends vuetify VTextField component.

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import { VTextField } from "vuetify/lib"

Vue.component('mTextField', {
  extends: VTextField,
  props: {
    outlined: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true
    }
  }
})
```

But always catch error while try to use mTextField component

```
Unexpected token 'export'
```

How can i make all *v-text-fields* components **outlined**?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Add transpile section in nuxt.config.js with 'vuetify/lib' worked for me

```js
  build: {
    transpile: ['vuetify/lib']
  },
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).